# Storing binary data in a PNG file using QImage::setText()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtgui, qimage

I need to read/store binary data in the metadata of a PNG image. Specifically, it will be gzipped data which has been serialized by Google's protobuf library.

I'm using the `QImage` library of Qt5 to load and store the images, so it would be extremely convenient if I could find a way to use some Qt library to add this binary data to the `QImage` I'm already using.

I see that the `QImage` class has a [`setText` method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#setText) which appears to do exactly what I want, except for one caveat: It takes a `QString` as an argument and not a `QByteArray`, and the `QString` constructor mangles my binary data.

How can I force `QString` to preserve my binary data, both when storing and loading? If that's not possible, is there some other way in Qt5 to add metadata to a PNG image?

Comment: gzipped data in metadata? I am sorry I do not follow... Perhaps, you could start with the use case? Also, what exactly is wrong about the from* conversion methods getting stuff from QBA?

Comment: The use case is caching an expensive computation that is crucial for the program's use of the image. I don't want to put it in a separate cache file because these images will be edited/moved/copied regularly, and storing the data in the image itself simplifies the task of determining whether the cached data exists and whether or not it's valid.

Comment: How exactly is the data mangled? If there are terminators (character '\0'), then the construction is supposed to stop there (see "Conversion from QByteArray to QString" here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq05-achtung.html#qstringisaunicodestring). Is it that or something else, can you tell?

Comment: @Elliott: currently, I am still struggling understanding your use case. Caching of what?

Comment: @Pukku Half of the characters in the QString are replaced with generic question mark characters. If I use [QString::fromUtf8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8-2) the null characters aren't an issue, but it ends up replacing almost all of the characters with question marks

Comment: @LaszloPapp It's caching an expensive computation pertaining to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to [encode the data as Base64](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#toBase64) before converting to QString, and then [decode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromBase64) when reading back. I do understand that this significantly reduces the benefits of your gzip compression, but at least you could try to see if that helps.

Comment: This works, although it's far from ideal. I may do this out of lack of other options.

Comment: A followup: Qt stores the text() data in the "zTXt" metadata field, which compresses its data. So, the fact that it's base64 doesn't matter, not does my gzip beforehand! So, I just convert it directly to base64 without compressing it, and the resulting base64 gets compressed by the png algorithm itself, negating the space concerns of the base64. I learned something!